# Manually stepping through a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I don't understand why I can't print out ints b and c in this way:

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
} myStruct;

int main(){

  myStruct MS;
  MS.a = 13;
  MS.b = 27;
  MS.c = 39;

  myStruct* pMS = &MS;

  printf("pMS = %u\n", pMS );
  printf("&a = %u\n", &pMS->a );  // addr of a is addr of struct
  printf("&b = %u\n", &pMS->b );  // addr of b is +4 from a
  printf("&c = %u\n", &pMS->c );  // addr of c is +8 from a

  printf("*pMS = %d\n",*(pMS) );
  printf("*pMS+4 = %d\n",*(pMS+4) );
  printf("*pMS+8 = %d\n",*(pMS+8) );
}
```

The terminal shows bogus values for b and c (at least, I think b and c should be located at pMS+4 and pMS+8):

```
gcc version 4.6.3

pMS = 1926301980
&a = 1926301980
&b = 1926301984
&c = 1926301988
*pMS = 13
*pMS+4 = 32765
*pMS+8 = 32765
```

Comment: So you're saying that when I go "pMS+4", it doesn't just add 4 to the address, but sizeof(myStruct)*4 ?

Comment: Even if the calculations were correct, it would still no be allowed. You can only use pointer arithmetic if the pointer points into an array, and `pMS` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pMS+4` is *not* the address of the integer located four bytes beyond the start of the structure. Additions to pointers are scaled based on the pointer type so, if it were a pointer to an integer, it would be four integers beyond the start (16 bytes if you have 32-bit ints). See, for example:

```
int someInt[2] = {4, 9}; // assume 4-byte int, big-endian
int *x = &someInt[0];

// | someInt[0] @ 0x1000 | someInt[1] @ 0x1004 |
// |       0,0,0,4       |       0,0,0,9       |
// |     x = 0x1000      |     x+1 = 0x1004    |
// |      *(x) = 4       |      *(x+1) = 9     |
```

However, it's even *worse* in your case since your pointer is to the actual *structure.* That means it's scaling by the size of the entire struct, three complete integers (plus padding if needed).

Comment: So how can I directly get at ints b and c without saying "pMS->b" and "pMS->c" ?

Comment: Oh, looks like I can cast the pointer to struct as a void*, add 4 to that number, cast it an int*, and then derefence that.

Comment: @CMDoolittle, better to use a `char*`. While gcc may allow void pointer arithmetic in non-pedantic mode, it's actually not supported by the standard.

Comment: @CMDoolittle: In strict standard C, you cannot do arithmetic on a `void *` (because `void` has no size, so there isn't a suitable value to add or subtract).  Some compilers, GCC (and Clang emulating GCC) treat `void *` as a `char *`, which has some justification but is not blessed by the standard.  You should convert to `char *`, do the addition, and convert back to an `int *`.  (I'm not sure that's all defined behaviour, but it is more nearly defined than incrementing a `void *`.)

Answer (score 1):

This line for example

```
printf("*pMS+4 = %d\n",*(pMS+4) );
```

When you add to the pointer, it is same as indexing to array, so equal to this:

```
printf("*pMS+4 = %d\n", pMS[4]);
```

Of course there is no array, so bogus struct value is passed.

And then printf can't print structs at all, %d prints something non-sensical.

Double undefined behavior, in other words.

Answer (score -1):

By perform some changes on code and implementing what [`@Jonathan Leffler`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) saying on comments this way works for me.

***Code***

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct t{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main(){

    struct t MS;
    MS.a = 13;
    MS.b = 27;
    MS.c = 39;

    struct t* pMS = &MS;

    printf("pMS =%p\n", pMS );

    printf("&a = %p\n", &pMS->a );  // addr of a is addr of struct
    printf("&b = %p\n", &pMS->b );  // addr of b is +4 from a
    printf("&c = %p\n", &pMS->c );  // addr of c is +8 from a

    printf("*pMS.a = %d\n", (* ((int *) ((void *) pMS))));//13

    printf("*pMS.b = %d\n", (* ((int *) ((void *) pMS)+1)));//27

    printf("*pMS.c = %d\n", (* ((int *) ((void *) pMS)+2)));//39

    return 0;

}
```

But also this works, as you see in @hyde answer working with this way not good. structures in C are packed depending on CPU architecture, Compiler means putting struct members in packed form, for example below struct takes 8 Bytes instead of 5.

```
struct example {
 int a;
 char b;
};
```

I use my way because i checked before, `sizeof(void *), sizeof(int *)` both return 4.

Consider these lines:

```
printf("*pMS.a = %d\n", (* ((int *) ((void *) pMS))));//13

printf("*pMS.b = %d\n", (* ((int *) ((void *) pMS)+1)));//27

printf("*pMS.c = %d\n", (* ((int *) ((void *) pMS)+2)));//39
```

***Why using +1 inside parenthesis cause accessing to our integers?***

On my system integers numbers occupy 4 bytes, as i expressed above `void *` and `int *` have size of same `4` Bytes.

First remove `void *` to simplify `(int *) (pMS) + 1`, behave pMS like an integer size, when we add one to it jumps to next for byte address that refers to 27.

I think adding `void *` is for remove UB from code, as pointer have `void *` type pointer to structure.

For this case removing `void *` also works.

At last

```
printf("pMS =%u\n", sizeof(MS) );//12(3 * 4)
printf("pMS =%u\n", sizeof(pMS) );//4
```

In my platform there is no any padding or packing, as see above entire structure hold 12 byte 3 integers with 4 bytes size. 
But `pMs` that is a pointer to first address of this structure, as first elements is integer this have 4 byte size.

***ToDO***

1. Edit post to add some further explain about pointers type and arithmetic.
2. Some extra things on difference between two way of using structure in this case.
3. Structure padding, packing depending on platform, OS, Compiler.
4. Why we see different address of structure when declare Global or Local inside main, that case different behavior in this case?